# Understanding definition of "skew" in the context of parallel lines

Tags: geometry

On page 35 of Smith's *Introductory Mathematics: Algebra and Analysis,* Smith writes the following:

> Finally, when you have a partition of a set $S$, it is often useful to have one representative from each set comprising the partition. A set of these representatives is called a *transversal* for the partition. If humanity is partitioned by gender, any set consisting of one male and one female is a transversal for the partition. We view a plane as a set, the elements of which are the geometric points comprising the plane. The plane can be partitioned into parallel straight lines, and then any straight line which is skew to the lines in the partition will suffice as a transversal. Such a skew straight line will intersect each of the family of parallel lines in exactly one point, as required.

I understand everything except for the use of the word "skew." After looking this up, I found (for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_lines)) that two lines are skew if they do not intersect and are not parallel. In $\mathbb{R}^2$ (or the plane), this isn't possible, as two distinct lines must be one or the other, so this would need to be upgraded to at least three-dimensional space. This is especially true because the author states that a skew line will intersect the family of parallel lines, though I'm not sure why it's "exactly one point." That leads me to believe that he's using a different definition. The mental image I had was a family of horizontal lines $y = c$ for every $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Those are certainly parallel and partition the plane.  The I could take the line, say, $x = 0$, which intersects each line $y = c$ exactly once. The problems are: (1) this line is perpendicular, not skew and (2) it intersects each line in the particular family of parallel lines, rather than intersecting the family itself once.

I'd appreciate some help with understanding this passage.

Comment: Here I would read "any straight line which is skew to the [family of parallel] lines in the partition" as any line not parallel to the family of parallel lines.  It would then be "transversal" as each one of its points is an intersection with exactly one of the the parallel lines and it insects each parallel line exactly once.  Your example of parallel lines of the form $y=c$ and the skew line $x=0$ would fit this undestanding

Comment: @Henry Thank you very much. The thing I don't understand, though, is that I believe the line $x = 0$ would intersect every horizontal line $y = c$, so it intersects every parallel line and thus the "family" of parallel lines infinitely many times. I don't know if this is what the author was intending.

Comment: I think that the author is being sloppy with language (the misuse of "comprise", for example), and that they are trying to use "skew" in a non-technical sense---in non-mathematical language, "skew" just means something like "at an angle" (near synonyms are words like "crooked" or "askew").  The choice of "skew" is unfortunate, as the word has a technical meaning in mathematics which pertains to lines, and is distinct from the intended meaning here.  A better word would probably be "oblique".  Better yet, "Any line which is *not* parallel to the lines composing the partition...".